# Slickgrid: Get event on value change.?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

How to get Event on value change in slickgrid. I find "grid.onclick" in examples, but it guess as it name shows it will get fire every time when i click on gird.

For example, I have a grid with three columns, name, lastname, and select(checkbox). I want when user select/unselect(change value of checkbox) checkbox i get notify.

```
var cols = [  
    {id:"fname", name:"First Name", field:"fname"},  
    {id:"lname", name:"Last Name", field:"lname"},
    {id: "select", name: "CheckBox",cssClass: "cell-effort-driven", field: "select", formatter: Slick.Formatters.Checkmark, editor: Slick.Editors.Checkbox}
];

var data = [
    {fname:"Jimmy", lname:"Page", select: true},  
    {fname:"Ritchie", lname:"Blackmore", select: false},  
    {fname:"Michael", lname:"Schenker", select: true}
];
```

I looked into SlickGrid object, it has onCellChange event. it not working good with checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it as follows,

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    if (args.cell == 3) { // Assuming that your checkbox is 3rd column
        //Your check box change event 
    }
}
```